# Is it possible to get a large page and a consecutive normal page

Tags: linux, windows, system-calls

Is it possible to get a large page and a consecutive normal page.

Im writing a runtime and I want to create 2M stack with a single 4K guard page. And it needs to scale to say 10 processes each with 10 threads.

Considering using a 2 Meg page because of TLB  misses this is normally not an issue with C / C++ but with region analysis we will  have more data ( entire regions) on the stack so its not just the  last pages that are hot.

Ben

Comment: Not sure why its closed its a perfectly legit question , it may be unusual but i do have good reasons which i have now added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Speaking for Linux, it is certainly possible, per se, to allocate a large page followed by a small region allocated normally:

```
mmap(base, 1 << 21, PROT_X, MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_HUGETLB | MAP_FIXED, -1, 0);
mmap(base + (1 << 21), 1 << 12, PROT_X, MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_FIXED, -1, 0);
```

However, I hardly think there's any way to get the kernel to properly manage the address for you such that you can get it to allocate addresses for you automatically while finding such an address that has a guaranteed free page following it, so you'll probably have to do address allocation manually.

EDIT: Actually, I'll have to revise that statement; there's a fairly simple way to get that guarantee, at least as long as you're not running multiple threads that may do allocation simultaneously. Just allocate two large pages, deallocate the latter, and the allocate the small page in the space that is now free:

```
p = mmap(NULL, 2 << 21, PROT_X, MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_HUGETLB, -1, 0);
mremap(p, 2 << 21, 1 << 21, 0);
mmap(p + (1 << 21), 1 << 12, PROT_X, MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_FIXED, -1, 0);
```

Comment: What about using virtual addresses ?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. All these addresses are virtual, of course. The kernel won't normally let you deal with physical addresses at all.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Just request a Large page and a normal page and remap via custom virtual address to be consecutive.